# Necesito saber como terminar la función usando javascript nativo

Tags: javascript, html, css

estoy haciendo un juego de preguntas y respuestas para la facultad, ya definí
las preguntas y las respuestas en dos arrays y hice una función para que me formulen distintas preguntas, lo único que me falta es seleccionar el elemento del input radio que esta seleccionado y ver si esa respuesta se encuentra en la posición 0 del array, que es donde estaría la respuesta correcta.Adjunto el código

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Juego de Preguntas</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">

</head>
<body> <!-- div preguntas y respuestas -->
 <div class="contenedor">
  <div id="preg"></div>
  <div id="Rtas"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Verificar respuesta" onclick="verificar()"> 
 </div> 
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //array preguntas
 var preguntas = [
 "¿Qué sabe hacer un desarrollador fullstack?",
 "¿Qué lenguaje sirve para hacer backend?",
 "¿Qué lenguaje es interpretado por el navegador?",
 ];
    //array respuestas
    var respuestas = [
    ["Ambos", "Solo Front-end", "Solo Back-end", "Ninguno"],
    ["PHP", "CSS3", "Bootstrap", "HTML5"],
    ["Javascript", "Java", "Cobol", "MS-DOS"]
    
    ];
   
   //Numero aleatorio de preguntas
   var indice_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random()*preguntas.length);

   var respuestas_posibles = respuestas[indice_aleatorio];

   var posiciones = [0,1,2,3];
   var respuestas_reordenadas = [];

   var respuesta_correcta;

   for(i in respuestas_posibles){
    var posicion_aleatoria = Math.floor(Math.random()*posiciones.length);
    if(posicion_aleatoria == 0){
     respuesta_correcta = i;
    }
    respuestas_reordenadas[i] =respuestas_posibles[posiciones[posicion_aleatoria]];
    posiciones.splice(posicion_aleatoria,1);
   }

   var texto_respuestas = "";
   for(i in respuestas_reordenadas){
    texto_respuestas += '<input type="radio" name="hola" value="'+i+'"<label>'+ 
    respuestas_reordenadas[i] + '</label> <br>';
   }
   //genera contenido en los elementos en el body
   document.getElementById('preg').innerHTML = preguntas[indice_aleatorio]
   document.getElementById('Rtas').innerHTML = texto_respuestas;

   function verificar(){
   respuesta_verdadera = document.querySelector("<input:checked>");
   }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RESPUESTA:**

El codigo para evaluar la generacion de respuesta aleatorias por medio del radio boton es el siguiente:

```
function verificar(){
     var checkedList = document.querySelector('input[name=hola]:checked').value;
     valor = respuestas_reordenadas[checkedList];
     resp = respuestas_posibles[0];
     if (resp == valor) {
        alert('Respuesta correcta : ' + resp + ' = ' + valor );
     } else {
        alert('Respuesta INCORRECTA : ' + resp + ' <> ' + valor );
     }
     console.log(respuestas_posibles[0]);
     console.log(valor);
}
```

Aqui coloco todo el codigo completo para probarlo en el interprete:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Juego de Preguntas</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilos.css">

</head>
<body> <!-- div preguntas y respuestas -->
 <div class="contenedor">
  <div id="preg"></div>
  <div id="Rtas"></div>
  <input type="button" value="Verificar respuesta" onclick="verificar()"> 
    </div> 
    

<script type="text/javascript">
 //array preguntas
 var preguntas = [
 "¿Qué sabe hacer un desarrollador fullstack?",
 "¿Qué lenguaje sirve para hacer backend?",
 "¿Qué lenguaje es interpretado por el navegador?",
 ];
    //array respuestas
    var respuestas = [
    ["Ambos", "Solo Front-end", "Solo Back-end", "Ninguno"],
    ["PHP", "CSS3", "Bootstrap", "HTML5"],
    ["Javascript", "Java", "Cobol", "MS-DOS"]
    
    ];
   
   //Numero aleatorio de preguntas
   var indice_aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random()*preguntas.length);

   var respuestas_posibles = respuestas[indice_aleatorio];

   var posiciones = [0,1,2,3];
   var respuestas_reordenadas = [];

   var respuesta_correcta;

   for(i in respuestas_posibles){
    var posicion_aleatoria = Math.floor(Math.random()*posiciones.length);
    if(posicion_aleatoria == 0){
     respuesta_correcta = i;
    }
    respuestas_reordenadas[i] =respuestas_posibles[posiciones[posicion_aleatoria]];
    posiciones.splice(posicion_aleatoria,1);
   }

   var texto_respuestas = "";
   for(i in respuestas_reordenadas){
    texto_respuestas += '<input type="radio" name="hola" value="'+i+'"<label>'+ 
    respuestas_reordenadas[i] + '</label> <br>';
   }
   //genera contenido en los elementos en el body
   document.getElementById('preg').innerHTML = preguntas[indice_aleatorio]
   document.getElementById('Rtas').innerHTML = texto_respuestas;

   function verificar(){
         var checkedList = document.querySelector('input[name=hola]:checked').value;
         valor = respuestas_reordenadas[checkedList];
         resp = respuestas_posibles[0];
         if (resp == valor) {
            alert('Respuesta correcta : ' + resp + ' = ' + valor );
         } else {
            alert('Respuesta INCORRECTA : ' + resp + ' <> ' + valor );
         }
         console.log(respuestas_posibles[0]);
         console.log(valor);
   }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```